# Same UI in iOS and Android

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

This one is a quick question regarding the possibility of having the same LnF (same look) on Android and iOS, is there an API that can provide something like this? SImilar to MAUI in MoSync or IwUI in marmaladeSDK?

Basically what I would like to do is to create my UI once for both iOS and Android using monodeveloper.

Note: Before anyone downvotes anymore, please take into account that this is a real requirement for a real project. The question is not without reason, since after looking at the documentation, I can see that Xamarin does not provide such solution, but other multi-platform SDKs do provide such solution, and since the mono ecosystem is vast, perhaps there is a third party library that can provide such functionality.

Comment: The iOS and Android UI design guidelines are different, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html. So giving your users "the same UI" on these two platforms itself is a questionable approach.

Comment: It's a requirement, not a question of using the proper guidelines, the application MUST have the same GUI in iOS, Android and WM6. Currently I am using MoSync MAUI to do this, it works, but there are features lacking like UTF-8 support for the UI, etc...

Comment: We saw developers who cannot fight against invalid requirements. But Xamarin's offer is limited to what you are aware of. The so call "cross platform SDKs" are almost all HTML5 based (hosted in a web browser control), so I don't think they are really cross platform (because they don't touch the platform yet). There might be something you want for Mono in the future, but I did not see any except Unity, http://unity3d.com/. It is primarily a game engine, but you can develop general applications with it. You might also checkout MonoGame http://monogame.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out http://ifactr.com/overview ? It is a paid product so I haven't tried it, but it might be at least work looking into. Other than this, no there is no cross-platform UI if you go the Mono route.

Taken directly from their page:

"But we learned that even with as much code sharing that MonoCross provides, for applications with significant UI layers, the burden of creating platform-specific UIs can be overbearing. So we created the iFactr UI abstraction layer, which allows developers to code to an abstract UI interface, and then reference our iFactr concrete implementations of that interface for all the mobile platforms, both as native UI implementations and HTML5 UI implementations.

While not a silver bullet for all mobile development, it is designed and optimized for rapidly creating data-driven UIs that enterprise users tend to demand. And because it’s integrated with MonoCross, you can mix-and-match your iFactr UI screens that are shared across platforms with screens that you can code to target specific platforms using the entire set of native APIs available on each mobile OS."

Comment: Well that is exaclty the kind of link I was looking for. Thanks, I will investigate this route

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately most of your code portability will be on the backend (non UI) when leveraging Monotouch. There are far too many inconsistencies with how an Android UI vs iOS UI are implemented respectively to their OS's.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suspected as much, I have been unable to find something similar to other toolkits.

Comment: No problem Dan, I suspect that if you were to create a very small specific application for a niche market perhaps you could move some of your UI layers into html5, then load them in the respective views of both an Android and iOS device. I don't suggest this yet though, there are a few frameworks that will be suitable fits for this task once they mature; until then split um up!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Android and iOS have different UI / UX metaphors.

Take this for example: http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-6-and-android-4/

The differences are fairly significant. If you use a development wrapper then you'll have to 100% rely on their tools. We've had experience with Titanium in the past and it wasn't good at all.